# How can I read a word list in chunks of 100?

Tags: ruby, file-io, jruby

I want to read words in chunk of 100 from a file and then process them.

I can do it adding additional counter etc, but is there a in-build command in one of the IO libs that does this. I wasnt able to find it

```
   require 'pp'
arr = []
i = 0
f=File.open("/home/pboob/Features/KB/178/synthetic/dataCreation/uniqEnglish.out").each(" ") { |word|
  i=i+1
  arr << word
  if i==100
    pp arr
    arr.clear
    i=0
  end
}
pp arr
```

Thanks!

P.S:
The file is too big to fit in memory, so I will have to use ".each "

Comment: this snippet shows that you think in imperative terms (do this, do that, increment, push, clear). Search for "ruby functional programming" in google, cool stuff. The rules are easy: no each, <<, clear, update, +=, ...

Comment: Maybe even better search for some pure functional programing language.

Comment: @Aleksandar: indeed, but you can apply functional principles in almost every language, and Ruby has powerful FP capabilities. Of course the OP will profit from learning a FP language (Haskell, Erlang, Scala, ML, ...)

Comment: Try using functional prinicples in assembly ;).

Answer (score 2):

> The file is too big to fit in memory, so I will have to use ".each "

Better than `each`, laziness with [enumerable-lazy](https://github.com/yhara/enumerable-lazy):

```
require 'enumerable/lazy'
result = open('/tmp/foo').lines.lazy.map(&:chomp).each_slice(100).map do |group_of_words|
  # f(groups_of words)
end
```

More on functional programming and laziness [here](http://code.google.com/p/tokland/w/edit/RubyFunctionalProgramming).

Comment: damn, I like to have a rating mod 5 ;-) care to explain the -1 so I can fix the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming one word per line, and the ability to slurp an entire file into memory:

```
IO.readlines('/tmp/foo').map(&:chomp).each_slice(100).to_a
```

If you are memory-constrained, then you can interate in chunks by specifying only the chunk size; no counter required!

```
File.open('/tmp/foo') do |f|
  chunk = []
  f.each do |line|
    chunk.push(line)
    next unless f.eof? or chunk.size == 100
    puts chunk.inspect
    chunk.clear
  end
end
```

That's pretty verbose, though it does make it clear what's going on with the chunking. If you don't mind being less explicit, you can still use slicing with an Enumerator:

```
File.open('/tmp/foo').lines.map(&:chomp).each_slice(100) {|words| p words}
```

and replace the block with whatever processing you want to perform on each chunk.

Comment: Thanks. The file is too big to fit in memory, so I will have to use ".each "

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I believe the implementation of "each_slice" is sufficiently lazy for your purposes.  Try this:

```
open('tmp/foo').lines.each_slice(100) do |lines|
  lines = lines.collect &:chomp   # optional
  # do something with lines
end
```

Not as elegant as tokland's solution but it avoids adding an extra dependency to your app, which is always nice.

I think this might be useful to you:
http://blog.davidegrayson.com/2012/03/ruby-enumerable-module.html

Comment: if the OP wants to do some side-effect with the result of the processing that's perfectly ok. The lazy gem is only needed if you want to map on the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's more straightforward to do:

```
File.open(filename) do |file|
  do_things(100.times.map{file.gets ' '}) until file.eof?
end
```